# I want to send JSON data from node-fetch api to the browser and update data every 900 miliseconds. How can I do that?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs, fetch-api, node-fetch

I have an issue where I want to send a response to my client-side. I have written a server with Express.js created all the routes and hooked all the things up together. My default view engine is configured as EJS. I don't want to just log the values to my console but I also want to send it to the client-side and update it dynamically. Hope this makes sense.

I have my node-fetch API code here:

```js
const express = require("express");
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
const router = express.Router();

router.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.send("API ONLINE")
})

function issFetch() {
  fetch("http://api.open-notify.org/iss-now.json")
    .then((response) => {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then((json) => {
      console.log(json);
      res.send(json)
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      return JSON.stringify(e);
    });
}

setInterval(issFetch, 900)

module.exports = router;
```

and my EJS file here

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>ISS Live Location API - Michael Grigoryan</title>
</head>
<body>
    <pre>
        <code lang="json">
            <%= data %>
        </code>
    </pre>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Server-Sent Events (SSE)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events)/[EventSource](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventSource) are the tool for this job.

The client requests the stream, and then events are sent from the server to the client as they happen.

There's no need for web sockets nor Socket.IO.  This is unidirectional communication... no need for that extra layer.  And certainly, I would not use polling as there is a great deal of overhead with this.

Another alternative, since you're tracking orbits, is to do the calculation client-side.  That way, you only have to send a small amount of data up front, and the current location can be live realtime without streaming data.